# Use of bolded variables in conference paper

Tags: publications, conference

I'm currently writing my first conference paper and am trying to determine a variable naming convention. I like the approach used by Di Carlo in [Dynamic  Locomotion  in  the  MIT  Cheetah  3  Through  Convex  Model-Predictive  Control](https://biomimetics.mit.edu/dynamic-locomotion-mit-cheetah-3-through-convex-model-predictive-control):

> [skipped irrelevant convention] Vectors are bold, upright, and lowercase (**a**,**ω**),  matrices  are  bold,  upright,  and  uppercase  (**A**,**Ω**),and  scalars  are  lowercase  and  italicized  (*a*,*ω*).

The conference recommends following the IEEE guidelines outlined [here](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html), which does not comment on the topic. I assume it is thus up to me as the author to decide. Is bolding variables frowned upon? Is there a alternative, preferred method?
Thank you!

Comment: Some papers will look fine with this notational convention; others will have so much bold stuff that they look terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For textbooks and self-published material, it is very good practice to follow a convention such as that proposed by Di Carlo, which is widely accepted as the general convention in mathematics.

However, it sounds like are talking about a submission to a conference to be collated and published as conference proceedings. This would typically have a review and editing process like submissions to any peer-reviewed journal would.  In this case, especially since they don't stipulate any conventions, it matters less because they will likely edit your notation where applicable so that all the submissions to the conference proceedings are consistent in notation and formatting.

Comment: Publisher Editing for conference proceedings? Almost not done at all - IEEE does not do this. Springer does this to a very limited degree (formatting of the title/author list and reference list), but certainly excluding the mathematical notation.

Comment: Then I guess it doesn’t matter either way, does it?

Comment: This is not a general convention in mathematics. Maybe in applied math, but certainly not in pure math.

Comment: @Earlien-reinstateMonica thank you, that makes perfect sense. I didn't even consider the conference would likely modify the notation to be consistent with the other submissions.